# WPF binding a property to a list of objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need some help to resolve a simple XAML binding problem I have.

I use MVVM pattern with 2 classes. Card and Board. I already created a model with a Card. The Card class is composed bu two properties only.

1. The value of my card.
2. The state of my card (downside or upside). The board contain a list of cards.

```
public class Card
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    public bool Upside { get; set; }

    public Card(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

class Board
{
    private List<Card> _cardList = new List<Card>();
    public List<Card> CardList
    {
        get
        {
            return _cardList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_cardList == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _cardList = value;
            raisePropertyChanged("CardList");
        }
    }

    public void Initialize()
    { 
       // Initialization of the card list
    }

    public void FlipCard()
    {
       // The rules and actions of my game
    }
}
```

After that I added all the `INotifyPropertyChanged` stuff on my card and board properties. I don't show you the code to stay as clear as possible.

On my `ViewModel` I only expose this:

```
public Board GameBoard { get; set; }
```

Of course I have a lot of other methods, property and command but nothing about card. The rule of my game and my cards are all in my Board class. My `ViewModel` only expose classes specific to my XAML design.

In my XAML file I have something like this. A card is a simple rectangle. I just need to bind the value of my card with the Fill property with the correct converter. The think is I only expose my Board so I need to write something like

```
Fill="{Binding **GameBoard.CardList[0]**
```

I don't generate my rectangles at runtime. Right now I have 4 card on my board then I wrote 4 time the Rectangle code and hardcoded 4 time the name ending by 01, 02, 03, 04. I just show you the 01 here:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <me:CardFillConverter x:Key="CardConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Rectangle x:Name="Card01" Fill="{Binding ??? Converter={StaticResource CardConverter}}" ... />
```

What is the correct binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have list of cards in your viewmodel then probably you have to somehow show them all in your view? It seems no sense to get them one by one with indexers. then you maybe should use something like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CardList}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Rectangle Fill="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource CardConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do your trick in the converter.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Card01" Fill="{Binding GameBoard.CardList Converter={StaticResource CardConverter} ConverterParameter = 0}" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go

Instead of hard coding for card you can leverage `ItemsControl` and specify a data template for the card's appearance and behavior

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GameBoard.CardList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Value,Converter={StaticResource CardConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

you may also choose to apply an `ItemsPanelTemplate` for defining card placement layout

eg

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GameBoard.CardList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Value,Converter={StaticResource CardConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```